# SoftAsert.assertEquals(actual,expected) method of TestNG is not functioning properly when we use WebElement's obj method .getCssValue("font-family")

Tags: java, selenium, testng, font-family

I am using **Selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar** file and **testNG version 6.14.3.** Using this I want to compare Web Element font-family from as input hard coded value and fetch from the website using selenium **driver.findElement**. now I have made method **SoftAssert** as code has mentioned bellow

This is I have tried to **SoftAssert**. Created method and passing as argument **WebElement obj, fontNameValid** as value **ProximaNova**. Now I get **font-family** from **HTML** is '**ProximaNova-Light**' idealy SoftAssert should **detecting this as bug** once we add **assertEqual** method but it will **pass** the test case. Please help.

```
CheckCSS.java

public static SoftAssert webElement_Check_CSS(WebElement obj, String fontNameValid) {

 String fontName1 = obj.getCssValue("font-family");
        System.out.println("Font Name from HTML :------->" + fontName1);
        System.out.println("Font Name as input :------->" + fontNameValid);

        softAssert.assertEquals(fontNameValid, fontName1,"WebElement is ["+obj.getText()+"] and Font name is not as per visuals");
 }       

DemoTest.java  

@Test   
public void Header(){   

System.out.println("++++++contactno+++++++++");
    String fontFamily ="proximanova";
    WebElement contact = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/a[2]"));
    softAssert = CheckCSS.webElement_Check_CSS(contact,fontFamily);
    //contact.click();
    }
```

```
Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#864}) on port 36987
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1569829278.198][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 77.
Sep 30, 2019 1:11:19 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
++++++contact no+++++++++
Font Name from HTML :------->ProximaNova-Light
Font Name as input :------->proximanova
Font Size:-------->15px
rgba(255, 232, 214, 1)
Font colour converted to hex:#ffe8d6
text-align:-------->center
PASSED: Header

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are missing is

softAssert.assertAll();

This will give results once after run all the softassert related assertion tests.

```
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
String ActualErrorMEssage = firstNameerrorXpath.getText;
String ActualErrorMEssage2 = secondNameNameerrorXpath.getText;
softAssert.assertEquals(ActualErrorMEssage,ExpectedErrorMEssage);
softAssert.assertEquals(ActualErrorMEssage2,ExpectedErrorMEssage);
softAssert.assertAll();
```